# "Modules not found" error during kernel install

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel

I have a question regarding a kernel installation. I downloaded a new version of net-next kernel source and I performed the following steps:

- `make allyesconfig`
- `make -j16`
- `make modules_install`
- `make install`

The problem is that when I try to execute `make install`, I get a "modules not found" error. I am confused here since someone else was able to make the kernel with the same procedure and I am unable to do the same (We both have root permission). Is there something extra I need to do to make sure those modules are visible/available?

Answer (score 1):

When `make install` is invoked, it will invoke a distribution-specific script to build the initrd.img, this script will lookup all the modules that required by this distribution, but because you have just compiled all modules into kernel as built-in via `make allyesconfig`, the script failed to lookup modules.

I can't reproduce your problem just now, I remember "modules not found" is just warnings, I always ignore it because the initrd.img was successfully built and the new kernel was successfully booted. If you do fail on "modules not found", you should re-config such modules from built-in modules to real loadable modules by manually via `make menuconfig` by this way: "modules not found" message contains module name, use the name to search through Makefiles to find out which CONFIG_XXX, and turn that CONFIG_XX to `=m`.

At the last, if you just want a newly built kernel, I suggest you use the distribution config instead `make allyesconfig`:

```
cd your_kernel_src
cp /boot/your_distribution_config .config
make menuconfig             # can exit it directly with nothing changed
make -j16
make modules_install
make install
# update the grub, if it is required for your distribution.
```

Answer (score 0):

You compiled the kernel with plain `make`, but not the modules. Run `make -j16 all modules`.

Comment: `make` will compiles the kernel and the modules

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the toolchain is aware of the kernel source tree you're working with. You have to set the environment variable `KERNEL_TREE` to the directory where your sources are. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147700/37538 for reference.