# Error installing kernel on Centos (from source)

Tags: kernel, compiling, centos

I am running GNU/Linux (Centos 6) on kernel 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64.  I am trying to update the kernel to 3.2.61.  I performed the following steps inside the 3.2.61 folder structure:

1. make menuconfig (took defaults- didn't add anything)
2. make
3. make modules
4. make modules_install
5. make install

On step 5, I received the following error:

```
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module lpc_ich
```

I tried `yum install lpc_ich`, but that did not exist.  This is my first time trying to install a new kernel.  I am not really sure if I am doing this correctly.

Could someone please help point me in the right direction?

Comment: check out these links: http://www.linux.org/threads/it-seems-that-i-have-insmod-wl-ko-in-the-kernel-but-the-wireless-card-still-not-working.5213/ and tutorial http://easylinuxtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-installcompile-latest-kernel-on.html

Comment: I'm almost sure that `modules_install` is not installing the modules you've compiled but others, from a different source tree. Have you created a symlink from `/usr/src/linux-3.2.61` (or whatever your downloaded sources are) to `/usr/src/linux`? See http://www.howtoforge.com/kernel_compilation_centos for reference.

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies.  I followed the instructions that @lgeorget provided.  I was able to build a rpm, install it and boot from it.

Comment: @Crackerman cool. I'll post a proper answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to give to the toolchain used to build the kernel the location of the kernel source tree. Otherwise, even if the compilation runs perfectly, the installation may fail with errors about missing modules or parts.

The kernel source tree is specified through the `KERNEL_TREE` environment variable. It defaults to `/usr/src/linux`. So either export this variable in the terminal in which you `make` the kernel:

```
export KERNEL_TREE=/usr/src/linux-3.2.61
```

or define a symlink from `/usr/src/linux-3.2.61` to /usr/src/linux`:

```
ln -s /usr/src/linux-3.2.61 /usr/src/linux
```

Of course, replace `/usr/src/linux-3.2.61` with the corresponding kernel source directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the missing module is selected to be installed in the kernel config file. Usually, the missing driver is noted to be loaded in the system and then it is expected to be available on the new kernel to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try only `make && make modules_install`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Comment: I only created this because i cold not comment, sorry about this